# How to change order in OrderDict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary

```
from collections import OrderedDict 

md = {"r3":"piz","r1":"pic","r9":"piz","r12":"pic","r19":"lia","r2":"kurcc","r21":"jes","r99":"pic","r111":"kurcc","r116":"kurcc","r211":"ar","r221":"buc"}

print (OrderedDict(sorted(md.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])))
```

I want to sort it,from lowest number.But I got

```
OrderedDict([('r1', 'pic'), ('r111', 'kurcc'), ('r116', 'kurcc'), ('r12', 'pic'), ('r19', 'lia'), ('r2', 'kurcc'), ('r21', 'jes'), ('r211', 'ar'), ('r221', 'buc'), ('r3', 'piz'), ('r9', 'piz'), ('r99', 'pic')])
```

How should I change my code to have r1,r2,r3 order?

Comment: Are all keys of the form `'r...'`?

Comment: Yes,they are that form.

Comment: maybe `key=int(t[0][1:])`

Answer (score 5):

If all keys are of the form `'r???'` with `???` an integer, we can use the following sorting key:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(md.items(), key=lambda t: int(t[0][1:])))
```

So here we first take the key with `t[0]` like you did yourself. Next we take the substring that starts at index 1 (so we drop the `'r'`), and finally we cast it to an `int(..)` to perform numerical comparisons.

This generates:

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(md.items(), key=lambda t: int(t[0][1:])))
OrderedDict([('r1', 'pic'), ('r2', 'kurcc'), ('r3', 'piz'), ('r9', 'piz'), ('r12', 'pic'), ('r19', 'lia'), ('r21', 'jes'), ('r99', 'pic'), ('r111', 'kurcc'), ('r116', 'kurcc'), ('r211', 'ar'), ('r221', 'buc')])
```

Comment: You could also enforce some form of data validation so you know it always has an `rNNN` pattern, eg: `sorted(md.items(), key=lambda L: int(re.match('r(\d+)$', L[0]).group(1)))`